# Отображение кнопки по таймеру

Tags: c#

Столкнулся с проблемой: Мне нужно, чтобы через некоторое время после запуска программы появлялась кнопка с действием, но у меня не получается это сделать (я только начал учится всем этим программистским вещам, поэтому прошу выясниться как можно проще). Вот, прошу помощи, ниже код кнопки.

```
private void Button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName("Thing"))
            {
                process.Kill();
            }

        }
        private void Button1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            button1.Hide();
            var stateTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(10);
            stateTimer.Elapsed += OnTimeEvent;
        }
        private void OnTimeEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            button1.Show();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var stateTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(); // таймер
            stateTimer.Elapsed += ShowBtn; // подписаваемся на событие 
            stateTimer.Interval = 10000; // интервал покажет кнопку через 10секунд
            stateTimer.Start(); // запуск таймера
            button1.Visible = false;

        }

    void ShowBtn(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
            {
                button1.Visible = true; // показать кнопку

            }));
        }

    }
```

Comment: Не работает, кнопка не видна на форме и спустя 10 секунд.

Comment: код запуска таймера должен находится в  методе Form_load

Comment: Спасибо большое!